# If ActionScript is a dying language, then where is the rescue language for using ActionScript skills?

Tags: actionscript-3

I heard that ActionScript will not be supported in the future.

Are there other languages similar to AS that I can write code in without problems?

Comment: Look at TypeScript, a variant of JavaScript that is similar to AS.

Comment: i meant if AS died by a heart attack ,whats the next language i should go to ,similar to AS

Comment: I'm curios, where did you heard that AS will be not supported in the future? Or is this hypothetical question? If you want to change language, it really depends what do you want to do. There are tons of languages that have similar syntax to AS, like javascript, java, c# and so on ...

Comment: in game development stack exchange they said adobe will drop her funds in flash AS ,and i want similar gaming language

Comment: It'll be very strange to drop their funds, after they spend all that money developing molehill. can you post me the link to that discussion? Maybe it's about AS2?

Comment: Oh, I think that I found that discussion. And I agree with the last comment - the Flash Player is dying (maybe), but not AIR. So there is no need to worry - at least not for few more years ...

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Haxe(NME)](http://www.haxenme.org/) is the closest language to AS.

the syntax varies a bit: Number->Float, int & uint -> Int etc.
package and class structures also, overall it was a pretty smooth transition.

here's a [list of the differences](http://www.haxenme.org/developers/documentation/actionscript-developers/), see for yourself :)

HaxeNME does cross compilation so it can target Flash, JS, C++, iOs, Android...
I'd say 70-80% of the code is the very same between targets and if you need some language specific methods, you can tell the compiler something like:

```
#if js
do something only JS target can do
#else 
for all other targets do this
#end
```

lots of former actionscript heroes joined the move and the community is very active, it reminds me of the the golden age of Flash.

there is hope :)

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript is [ECMAScript 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) or [ISO/IEC 16262](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=55755).

[There are several dialects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) of ECMA-262 including JavaScript, JScript, and J# as well as universal programming languages such as [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) capable of cross compiling.

[Adobe roadmap for the Flash runtimes](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html) gives insight to future direction of Flash and ActionScript.